# Include Twig with multiple arrays?

Tags: twig

Im importing a template and using an array to provide values to placeholders:

```
  {% set stuff = {
    title: 'my title'
  }
  %}

 {% include "template.twig" with stuff %}
```

This is working fine but how can I include 2 arrays? The following isnt working:

```
  {% set stuff = {
    title: 'my title'
  }
  %}

  {% set moreStuff = {
    body: 'Some body text'
  }
  %}


  {% include "template.twig" with {stuff, moreStuff} %}
```

Comment: have you aready tried with the [merge](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/merge.html) twig filter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done with merge:

```
{% include "template.twig" with stuff|merge(moreStuff) %}
```

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/merge.html